# Sistema De Subtração Por Input Com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um sisteminha de subtração via input só que está acontecendo o seguinte
por exemplo se o valor é 30 e quero subtrair 29,50 ao invés de aparecer 0,50 ele aparece 0,5 não aparece o 0 no final, e também se for 29,60 e eu quero subtrair 29,50 ao invés de aparecer 0,10 ele aparece 0,10000000000000142

o codigo é esse

```
<script language="javascript">
            function calcular(){
                var valor1 = document.getElementById("valor1").value; //pega o valor do imput do valor 1
                var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value; //pega o valor do imput do valor 2
                var subtracao = valor1 - valor2; //calcula =D

                //insere no html da div subtraçao o imput com o valor da calculo
                document.getElementById("subtracao").innerHTML = "<span class='info-box-number'>"+ subtracao +""+'R$' +" </span>";
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o [toFixed(2)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

```
<script language="javascript">
            function calcular(){
                var valor1 = document.getElementById("valor1").value; //pega o valor do imput do valor 1
                var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value; //pega o valor do imput do valor 2
                var subtracao = parseFloat(valor1 - valor2).toFixed(2); //calcula =D

                //insere no html da div subtraçao o imput com o valor da calculo
                document.getElementById("subtracao").innerHTML = "<span class='info-box-number'>"+ subtracao +""+'R$' +" </span>";
            }
</script>
```